# ProcessLifecycleOwner not working after updating app compat to 1.4.1

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-lifecycle, application-lifecycle

I'm investigating a weird issue, where we changed the `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` from `1.3.1` to `1.4.1` and all of a sudden our `LifecycleObservers` observing process lifecycle stopped emitting any events.

I'm also using `"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"`, I know that this is already deprecated, but it works flawlessly if appcompat is `1.3.1`

I have set the correct application name in the Manifest, I have included this provider as required per docs.

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            tools:node="remove" />
```

Example of initialisation, which doesn't work. This object is injected in the `Application` class and lifecycle observer is getting added, but `onStart` and `onStop` are never called.

```
class AppLifecycle @Inject constructor(
    private val foregroundProxy: AppLifecycleProxy
) : LifecycleObserver {

    init {
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onStart() {
        foregroundProxy.onStarted()
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onStop() {
        foregroundProxy.onStopped()
    }
}
```

EDIT:
As per @EpicPandaForce comment, changing the the provider block in Manifest to:

```
 <provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities=\"${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node=\"merge">
    <!-- If you are using androidx.startup to initialize other components -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer"
        android:value="androidx.startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
 </provider>
```

And replacing the `"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"` dependency with `"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.4.1"` has fixed this problem

Comment: Have you tried with app compat `1.6.0-alpha01` version?

Comment: Yes, the problem was in the provider block which disabled AndroidX StartUp process

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a good bet that the reason there has been changes on your side is because ProcessLifecycleOwner's initialization was reworked to use the Jetpack Startup library, which relies on a ContentProvider, therefore only does initialization in a process's main process.

In the actual code for ProcessLifecycleOwner, it says:

> ```
> /**
>  * Initializes {@link ProcessLifecycleOwner} using {@code androidx.startup}.
>  */
> public final class ProcessLifecycleInitializer implements Initializer<LifecycleOwner> {
>
>     @NonNull
>     @Override
>     public LifecycleOwner create(@NonNull Context context) {
>         AppInitializer appInitializer = AppInitializer.getInstance(context);
>         if (!appInitializer.isEagerlyInitialized(getClass())) {
>             throw new IllegalStateException(
>                     "ProcessLifecycleInitializer cannot be initialized lazily. \n"
>                             + "Please ensure that you have: \n"
>                             + "<meta-data\n"
>                             + "    android:name='androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer' \n"
>                             + "    android:value='androidx.startup' /> \n"
>                             + "under InitializationProvider in your AndroidManifest.xml");
>         }
>         LifecycleDispatcher.init(context);
>         ProcessLifecycleOwner.init(context);
>         return ProcessLifecycleOwner.get();
>     }
>
>     @NonNull
>     @Override
>     public List<Class<? extends Initializer<?>>> dependencies() {
>         return Collections.emptyList();
>     }
> }
> ```

And the commit that made it use `androidx.startup` in 2021-03 says this:

> "`lifecycle-process` now uses `androidx.startup` to initialize process
> lifecycle owner.
>
> Previously, this was being done by
> `androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer`.
>
> If you used `tools:node="remove"` the `ContentProvider` being used to
> initialize process lifecycle in the past, then you need to do the
> following instead.
>
> ```
> <provider
>  android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
>  android:authorities=\"${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
>  android:exported="false" tools:node=\"merge"> <!-- If you are using
>  androidx.startup to initialize other components --> 
>         <meta-data
>           android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer"
>           android:value="androidx.startup" /> 
> </provider>
> ```
>
> ```
> (or)
>
>
>      <!-- If you want to disable androidx.startup completely. -->
>      <provider android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
>      android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
>      tools:node="remove"> 
>     </provider>
>
> "
> ```

So the snippet you added specifically disables the AndroidX StartUp process and therefore your ProcessLifecycleOwner won't get initialized.

---

By the way, Google did NOT provide a way to manually install the ProcessLifecycleOwner if you disable the automatic start-up process, but to achieve it, you just need to mimic what they are doing. For example, if you needed to use ProcessLifecycleOwner in a multi-process app, then you'd need to not use the ContentProvider.

In that case, you can create a ***Java*** file in a package called `androidx/lifecycle`:

```
public class ProcessLifecycleInitializerAccessor {
    public static LifecycleOwner initialize(Application context) {
        LifecycleDispatcher.init(context);
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.init(context);
        return ProcessLifecycleOwner.get();
    }
}
```

But in your place, you probably just have to remove the snippet that removes your ContentProvider.

Comment: Updating the provider block has fixed this issue, thanks

Comment: tools:node="remove" should be removed from ProcessLifecycleInitializer meta-data , otherwise app will crash. Please update your answer @EpicPandaForce.

Comment: @Murat correct, updated

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Just wondering how we can access `android/lifecycle` and add the above class ?

Comment: @droidev you create a packag called `android` which contains a package called `lifecycle`, then if you create a Java class, it can access those functions because they are merely package-internal.

Answer (score 8):

There was an upgrade were `androidx.lifecycle` started using `androidx.startup` to initialize.
So, if this code was in your manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

Then you can completely remove that code, or use `tools:node="merge"` instead of `remove`.

You need to verify in the Merged Manifest that `androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer` is being initialized.

Answer (score 7):

if you are using lifecyle library, add this

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"    
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"
```

Answer (score 4):

My workaround might not work for everyone. But here's the basic idea. Note, my app is using `WorkManager`.

### Step 1:

Change

```
def lifecycle_version = '2.2.0'
// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
```

to

```
def lifecycle_version = '2.5.1'
// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
// LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
// optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"
```

---

### Step 2:

Change

```
<!-- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration -->
<!-- If you want to disable android.startup completely. -->
<provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    tools:node="remove">
</provider>
```

to

```
<!-- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration -->
<provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node="merge">
    <!-- If you are using androidx.startup to initialize other components -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:value="androidx.startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
</provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem when I disabled databinding.

Adding this solved it

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"
```